# Interceptor PreHandle ContentCachingRequestWrapper request Empty

Tags: spring, filter, request, interceptor

Request from Interceptor preHandle is empty.
Why is this happening?

```
@Component
public class CustomServletWrappingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappingRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest);
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrappingResponse = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse);
        filterChain.doFilter(wrappingRequest, wrappingResponse);
        wrappingResponse.copyBodyToResponse();
    }

}
```

preHandle request is Empty

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        if (CallCountUtil.isMimeTypeJson(request)) {
            ContentCachingRequestWrapper cachingRequestWrapper = (ContentCachingRequestWrapper) request;
            String json = new String(cachingRequestWrapper.getContentAsByteArray());
        }
}
```

afterCompletion request is ok.

```
@Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws IOException {
        if (CallCountUtil.isMimeTypeJson(request)) {
            ContentCachingRequestWrapper cachingRequestWrapper = (ContentCachingRequestWrapper) request;
            String json = new String(cachingRequestWrapper.getContentAsByteArray());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read [the javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ContentCachingRequestWrapper.html) you would have the answer.

> This class acts as an interceptor that **only caches content as it is being read but otherwise does not cause content to be read**. That means if the request content is not consumed, then the content is not cached, and cannot be retrieved via `getContentAsByteArray()`.

In the `preHandle` method the request hasn't been consumed yet and thus `getContentAsByteArray()` is empty. In the `afterCompletion` the request has been consumed and the cache has been filled and thus `getContentAsByteArray()` does return a value.

Basically you shouldn't care if it is a `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`, just read the `InputStream` from the `HttpServletRequest` as you normally would do.

Something like this.

```java
String json = StreamUtils.copyToString(request.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: First of all, please understand that my English is very poor.

The controller processed the ContentCachingRequestWrapper through the filter because requestBody is not available when using requestet.getInputstream.

At this point, I realized that it was not available in preHandle, so I knew that I needed to implement logic in AOP or filter, or customize the RequestBodyAdviceAdapter.

Thank you.

Comment: The request is perfectly available through `getInputStream` but **only once** as you can only consume the request once. Which is why you need the caching. There is no need for further downstream components to be concerned with this and those can now just use `getInputStream` of whatever they like.